# How to make MongoDB Aggregation query very fast?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

MongoDB Query is running very slow. How to make it fast. My observation is after using `"$group"`, query is getting slower. Without `"$group"`, it is working in milliseconds.

What part should I change in Query-2. Please guide.

Query 1 : running fast

```js
db.getCollection("visitor_logs").aggregate([
    { "$match": { "conversation_type": "livechat" } },
    {"$match": {"conversation_status": "Open"}},
    { "$lookup": { "from": "chathistory", "localField": "session_id", "foreignField": "session_id", "as": "session" } },
    { "$unwind": { "path": "$session", "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays": true } },
    { "$replaceRoot": { "newRoot": { "$mergeObjects": ["$$ROOT", "$session"] } } },
    { "$match": { "agent.id": "b4c0805f-c2e1-4704-9fd3-c6014c5f5b36" } },
    { "$match": { "channel": "website" } },
])
```

Query 2 : running very slow.

```js
db.getCollection("visitor_logs").aggregate([
    { "$match": { "conversation_type": "livechat" } },
    { "$lookup": { "from": "chathistory", "localField": "session_id", "foreignField": "session_id", "as": "session" } },
    { "$unwind": { "path": "$session", "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays": true } },
    { "$replaceRoot": { "newRoot": { "$mergeObjects": ["$$ROOT", "$session"] } } },
    { "$match": { "agent.id": "b4c0805f-c2e1-4704-9fd3-c6014c5f5b36" } },
    { "$match": { "channel": "website" } },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "",
            "open_count": { "$sum": { "$cond": [{ "$eq": ["$conversation_status", "Open"] }, 1, 0] } },
            "close_count": { "$sum": { "$cond": [{ "$eq": ["$conversation_status", "Closed"] }, 1, 0] } },
            "pending_count": { "$sum": { "$cond": [{ "$eq": ["$conversation_status", "Pending"] }, 1, 0] } },
            "assigned_count": { "$sum": { "$cond": [{ "$eq": ["$conversation_state", "assigned"] }, 1, 0] } },
            "unassigned_count": { "$sum": { "$cond": [{ "$eq": ["$conversation_state", "unassigned"] }, 1, 0] } },
            "unattended_count": { "$sum": { "$cond": [{ "$eq": ["$conversation_state", "unattended"] }, 1, 0] } }
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: How long does the first query take if you append `.itcount()` to the end?

Comment: Can you move the last two `"$match"` stages into a pipeline in `"$lookup"`?

Comment: @user20042973 first query run within 1 second

Comment: @rickhg12hs ...actually agent.id and channel will get after $unwind stage. because both are available in chathistory group

Comment: That's what I thought, so `{ "$lookup": { "from": "chathistory", "localField": "session_id", "foreignField": "session_id", "as": "session", "pipeline": [ { "$match": { "agent.id": "b4c0805f-c2e1-4704-9fd3-c6014c5f5b36", "channel": "website" } } ] } }` would filter out the unneeded docs earlier, yes?

Comment: You might also consider replacing your `"$group"` with `{"$group": {"_id": "$conversation_status", "count": {"$sum": 1}}}`.

Comment: @rickhg12hs by using createIndex, we can make mongo query faster